# Como converter uma data_atual para a data_formatada com php?

Tags: php

Como converter a data "2017-06-19 15:09:00.000000" para "19-06-2017" com php.

Comment: usa estilo orientado a objetos ou estruturado?

Comment: e tem alguma coisa feita aí? se sim compartilha

Comment: Estou recebendo um Json que tem a data no formato "2017-06-19 15:09:00.000000" e gostaria de guardar isso em uma variável no formato brasileiro "19-06-2017".

Comment: Acho melhor vc guardar dessa forma mesmo e na hora de exibir formatar para o formato brasileiro

Comment: Como formato isso para o formato brasileiro?